# Delete Object from S3 after Upload with SDK

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

if I upload an object from dashboard, I can delete it with aws-sdk-go but if I upload with aws-sdk-go, I cannot delete object from AWS S3 and i don't have error.

This is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ..."
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::storage.test.com/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::361908204985:user/caio"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::storage.test.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I upload the file with this code:

```
_, err := s.client.PutObject(&s3.PutObjectInput{
    Body:          file,
    Bucket:        s.bucket,
    Key:           "test/foo/a.png",
    ACL:           aws.String("private"),
})
```

and I delete the file with this code:

```
_, err := s.client.DeleteObject(&s3.DeleteObjectInput{
    Bucket: s.bucket,
    Key:    aws.String("test/foo/a.png"),
})
```

Why delete action fail?

Comment: I'm not convinced this even compiles. `s3.PutObjectInput.Key` is supposed to be of type `*string`, but you are assigning a `string`. `i don't have error` - where? No compilation error? `s.client.DeleteObject...` doesn't return an error?

Comment: Yes, It compiles. I don't have compilation error and the code works fine, but if I try to delete a file uploaded with this code, it doesn't return an error but the file is not deleted from S3.

Comment: Seems like S3 doesn't actually delete the object right away. Your `DeleteObject(...)` call is probably succeeding but the object is just being "marked" for deletion and might take some extra time to be removed. I would log out the response (first return variable you're ignoring) to see what you get back. Read more here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.DeleteObject

Comment: Thanks @Snarf, I run a test...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for your reference. I am using `aws-sdk-go-v2`.
Make sure your IAM user has sufficient S3 permissions.

```golang
import(
    "context"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

func configS3() *s3.Client {

    creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(os.Getenv("S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID"), os.Getenv("S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"), "")
    
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithCredentialsProvider(creds), config.WithRegion(os.Getenv("S3_REGION")))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } 

    return s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)

}

func DeleteImageFromS3(echoCtx echo.Context) error {
    
    awsClient := configS3()

    input := &s3.DeleteObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("mybucket"),
        Key:    aws.String("pic.jpg"),
    }

    _, err := awsClient.DeleteObject(context.TODO(), input)

    if err != nil {

        fmt.Println("Got an error deleting item:")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return 

    }

    return echoCtx.JSON(http.StatusOK, "Object Deleted Successfully")

}
```

Reference: https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/code-examples/s3/deleteobject/

Answer (score 0):

the same issue, after some short research about this case, I think s3 [DeleteObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObject.html) function it's not working properly when we want to use delete object s3.

I try to use [s3manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#NewDeleteListIterator) to do it and it works, this function can make a delete marker on an s3 object (versioning enabled), and I think it is the best choice so far.